# C# WebView2 http uri is coming up as about:blank#blocked

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I am using WebView2 within Wpf to render html documents.
These html documents can contain *a* elements which I need to open in the default browser. In order to do this, I intercept the webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting event and open the url in the default browser.

When I try to fetch the Uri from the webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting event, the url is correctly returned for https urls but not http urls. Http urls will have their uri returned as "about:blank#blocked".

```
 private void CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         string uri = e.Uri.ToString();

         if (uri.StartsWith("https://") || uri.StartsWith("http://"))
         {
             Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(uri) { UseShellExecute = true });
             e.Cancel = true;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         webView.Source = new Uri(e.Uri.ToString());
         Log.AddException("Unable to open hyperlink in default browser due to error:  " + ex.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks everyone!

I've had a go at disabling web security like below but with no avail:

```
CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("disable-web-security");
    CoreWebView2Environment environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options);
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);
```

I also thought to look in the event's request headers to try and fish out the url but again with no luck.

Comment: Can you verify that the default browser on that machine for that user will load an unsecure web-page in the first place? There's plenty of configuration spots on a windows machine that would cause this which have absolutely nothing to do with your code. Enterprise level configurations would do it. I'm pretty sure I can't hit an http:// site from my office network, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a malformed href with ” instead of ".

```
<a href=”http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/”>HTTP Link</a>
```

The whole html document I was using for testing is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Test</h2>
<div>
    <p>No target attribute: </p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.bbc.com/">BBC News</a><br/>
    <a href=”http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/”>HTTP Link</a>

    <p>Target attribute: </p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google with target attribute: blank</a><br/>
    <a href="https://www.bbc.com/" target="_parent">BBC News with target attribute: parent</a><br/>
    <a href="https://www.bbc.com/" target="_top">BBC News with target attribute: top</a><br/>

    <p>Relative link: </p>
    <a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a>
    <a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a>
    <a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a>
    <a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon changing to the correct double quote character the HTTP link works.